# How can I sign my app with "APK Signature Scheme v3 and v4"?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, sign

Here in the docs, there is the explanation about signature v3 and v4 :
https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3

But when I try to sign my app in android studio using Build>Generate signed apk/bundle,  I can just check checkboxes for v1(jar signature) and v2(full apk signature) and there is no option for v3 signature.

How can I sign my App using signature scheme v3 and v4?

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#v3-v4-signing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of today, Android Studio  supprot v3 and v 4 with Android Gradle Plugin 4.2
To enable one or both of these formats in your build, add the following properties to your module-level build.gradle or build.gradle.kts file:

```
android {
   ...
   signingConfigs {
      config {
          ...
          enableV3Signing = true
          enableV4Signing = true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this: Gradle 7 and only v1 and v2 signature were included.

Comment: You need also add this line in buildTypes -> release block:

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}

Comment: The above configs enableV3Signing & enableV4Signing are not working, do I have to upgrade my gradle version to 7 or later version of it?

Comment: has anyone find anything yet? please share their findings

Answer (score 12):

To manually create the signed build using Command line.

Please find the steps to create v3 and v4 scheme signed build,

1. Select build-tools\30.0.0 or later version.

   Note: You can find the build-tools folder inside the SDK location.

   *\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0*
2. Zipalign - Align the unsigned APK

> zipalign -v -p 4 app-production-debug.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk

Note:

app-production-debug.apk - a. Apk file you have created from Android studio by Build-> Build Bundles(s)/APK(s)-> Build APK(s)

my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk - The file will be created in the same directory(You can define your path as well).

3. Apksigner - Sign your APK with your private key

> apksigner sign --ks release-keystore.jks --out my-app-release.apk
> my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk

Note:
a. release-keystore.jks
- Keystore file we have configured in the build.gradle file

```
   android {
                signingConfigs {
                        production {
                            storeFile file('release-keystore.jks')
                            storePassword 'XXXX'
                            keyAlias = 'AAAAA'
                            keyPassword 'XXXX'
                        }
                }
            buildTypes {
                        release {
                            ...............
                            signingConfig signingConfigs.production 
               
                        }
            }
        }
```

b. my-app-release.apk - Signed release build will be generated in the same directory(You can define your path as well).

4. Verify:

> apksigner verify --verbose my-app-release.apk

Update to verify v4:

> apksigner verify -v -v4-signature-file my-app-release.apk.idsig my-app-release.apk

5. You can see the schemes that verified in the release apk.

   Verifies

   Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true

   Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true

   Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true

   Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): true

Comment: Thank you. I will test your solution later

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But can you explain a little here.

Comment: Please refer https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3 for more info

Comment: @Srinivasan This gives me v1 and v2 as true, but doesn't gives me anything for v3. Do we have to mention something for v3 explicitly ? Can you please help me v3 sign the apk as well??

Comment: AGP 4.2 now supports v3 and v4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67423751/9636

Comment: I get apksigner:command not found when I run apksigner command on Android Studio

Answer (score 3):

You should upgrade your gradle version to 7.0+ and set the `signingConfigs` in your `build.gradle` file as below

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        v1SigningEnabled true
        v2SigningEnabled true
        enableV3Signing = true
        enableV4Signing = true
        storeFile XXXX
        storePassword XXXX
        keyAlias XXX
        keyPassword XXX
    }
}
```

Then just create your apk as normal.^_^

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and mine, which was written one month before?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it just worked enabling them in the corresponding configuration:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        v1SigningEnabled true
        v2SigningEnabled true

        enableV3Signing = true
        enableV4Signing = true

        storeFile file("${project.rootDir}/debug.keystore")
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'android'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
}
```

Just ensure your gradle version supports them in order to be used.

Comment: Not working in the latest versions February 2023.

Answer (score 0):

you can use v1SigningEnabled  and v2SigningEnabled  in signing config

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("$rootDir/keystore/demo.jks")
        storePassword ""
        keyAlias ""
        keyPassword ""
        v1SigningEnabled false
        v2SigningEnabled true
    }
}
```