# How to Enable v3 & v4 App Support for Android APK File

Tags: android, android-studio, keytool, apksigner, apk-signing

I have pasted the below command in the **Terminal / Command Prompt** and found the output from the below image file. So how do I enable or set **v3 & v4 Signature Scheme** to **true** which is currently getting **false**

> java -jar
> /Users/Admin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/lib/apksigner.jar
> verify -v --print-certs /Users/Admin/Downloads/TestApp.apk

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Do I have to change anything inside the app level **build.gradle** file?
2. Currently I am referring the below sites for the **v3 & v4 Signature Scheme** 
   2.1 **v3 Signature Scheme:** https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3
   2.2 **v4 Signature Scheme:** https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v4

Comment: Have you seen: [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020469/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes, I have already added those oarams to the SigningConfig

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sign my app with "APK Signature Scheme v3 and v4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248088/how-can-i-sign-my-app-with-apk-signature-scheme-v3-and-v4)

Comment: In short, use a more recent version of apksigner, e.g. by updating the SDK tools.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            ...
            v1SigningEnabled false
            v2SigningEnabled true
            enableV3Signing = true
            enableV4Signing = true
        }
    }
}
```

To be able to verify the v4 signature check this:
[APK signature scheme v4 can't be verified with apksigner](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239313/apk-signature-scheme-v4-cant-be-verified-with-apksigner)